# Primefaces/jsf Media Tag to Play WebM Files in chrome browser

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to know what type of settings are required to play .webm media files using the PrimeFaces  tag.
My code looks like the following:

This works when I try to open the page in Microsoft Internet Explorer, but I am not able to see the video in Google Chrome.
I am looking for a way to embed videos using PrimeFaces that does not involve plugins.

My code looks like the following:

```
<p:media style="margin: auto; display: block" id="part1Video" 
rendered="true" player="windows" width="600" height="400" 
value="C:\...\Part1_Intro_(new).webm"/>
```

Comment: Is 'c:\...' on the server or client?  Are you using 'http://127.0.0.1/localhost' to look at the application? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: c:\..\ is on client. Yes I am using '127.0.0.1/localhost' to look at the application. Browser console message 'Not allowed to load local resource: file:///c:/../Part1_Intro_(new).webm?pfdrid c=true <br/>. File on its own when called from the Chrome browser works perfectly. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you meant the file is on the server, because I know no cases where the server need to play a video that exist in the client's own computer to the client itself.

Anyway you could try making a servlet to stream your webm

```
@WebServlet(name = "WebmViewer", urlPatterns = {"/WebmViewer"})
public class WebmViewer extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String path = request.getParameter("path");
            Path p = Paths.get(path);
            byte[] webmbytes = Files.readAllBytes(p);
            response.setContentType("video/webm");
            response.getOutputStream().write(webmbytes);
            response.getOutputStream().flush();
            response.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The url would be something like

```
http://localhost:8080/WebApp/WebmViewer?path=F:\java\mp3\Loop.webm
```

Then use quicktime to play it

```
<p:media value="WebmViewer?path=F:\java\mp3\Loop.webm" player="quicktime"/>
```